# Cant able to upgrade PHPUnit in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, phpunit, pear

I am trying to upgrade PHPUnit to latest version but I am getting error "install failed".

I installed PHPUnit with some online tutorial.

```
$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 5.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

I believe the current version is 5.5. I am trying the following command.

```
$ sudo pear install -a -f phpunit/PHPUnit

Attempting to discover channel "phpunit"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "phpunit"...
unknown channel "phpunit" in "phpunit/PHPUnit"
invalid package name/package file "phpunit/PHPUnit"
install failed
```

I tried different command from another tutorial:

```
$ pear config-set auto_discover 1
config-set succeeded
$ pear upgrade
downloading Archive_Tar-1.4.2.tgz ...
Starting to download Archive_Tar-1.4.2.tgz (20,624 bytes)
........done: 20,624 bytes
upgrade ok: channel://pear.php.net/Archive_Tar-1.4.2

$ pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit

Attempting to discover channel "pear.phpunit.de"...
downloading phpunit.de ...
Starting to download phpunit.de (5,392 bytes)
.....done: 5,392 bytes
unknown channel "pear.phpunit.de" in "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
invalid package name/package file "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
install failed
```

I am new to Ubuntu so kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

> sudo pear install -a -f phpunit/PHPUnit

PHPUnit [discontinued the installation using PEAR](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method) in April 2014. The most recent versions that can be installed using PEAR are 3.7.35 and 4.0.17.

Take a look at the [PHPUnit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/5.5/en/installation.html) and pick one of the methods described there. Make sure your system passes the requirements (PHP version) before starting.

The [PHP Archive (PHAR)](https://phpunit.de/manual/5.5/en/installation.html#installation.phar) installation method can be used to install PHPUnit globally or only for one user. To install it globally, run `which phpunit` before installation to find out if your current version is installed in `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` or somewhere else and put the path returned by this command in the `mv` command. To install it locally just skip the `mv` command (but remember where you installed it or put it into the path).

The [Composer method](https://phpunit.de/manual/5.5/en/installation.html#installation.composer) is easier and it is the best if your project already uses Composer to manage its dependencies. Its main advantage is that different projects that uses different versions of PHP can use different versions of PHPUnit.

If your current version of PHPUnit was installed by Ubuntu then the best method to upgrade it is to use the tools provided by Ubuntu. Run:

```
sudo apt-get install phpunit
```

to upgrade PHPUnit to the most recent version provided by Ubuntu. Unfortunately, like all the other distributions, Ubuntu doesn't provide the cutting edge versions of software programs but an older, stable, well-tested version.

Comment: Attempting to discover channel "phpunit"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "phpunit"...
unknown channel "phpunit" in "phpunit/PHPUnit"
invalid package name/package file "phpunit/PHPUnit"
install failed

Comment: Did you actually read the answer you got from axiac? You are getting these errors because you are trying use an installation method that no longer exists.